# Can't get android to output Lat & Lng consistently to Textview

Tags: java, android, gps

I have made it so it does output the Lat & Lng when I fresh install the APK on my phone but it writes it 5 times but after that, it doesn't work... How do I get it to work?

In the logs, it outputs that I'm pressing the button but doesn't seem to do anything. The device I'm testing on is a Galaxy S7 Edge running Android 7

Code Below

```
    getLocation = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listenLocation = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            townName.append(location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());



        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           requestPermissions(new String[]{
                   android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                   android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET
           }, 10);
            return;
        }
    }else{
        configureButton();
    }



}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                configureButton();
            return;
    }
}

private void configureButton() {
    location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            getLocation.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listenLocation);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `FusedLocationProviderAPI` with `GPSChecker`

Answer (score 0):

Use belo code in `onLocationChanged()` method....

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Location"));
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
     latLngString = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
}
```